# Daily report by date with mssql for mutiple column

Tags: sql-server

I want to display daily report like this

```
          Fulltime Contract Casual
2018/06/04  1       0        0
2018/06/05  1       0         0
2018/06/06  0       1         1
2018/06/07  2       1         0
2018/06/08  1       1         1
2018/06/09  0       1         1
```

but what I have is like this

```
Date       Jobtype Meal
2018/06/04 Fulltime 1
2018/06/05 Fulltime 1
2018/06/06 Casual   1
2018/06/06 Contract 1
2018/06/07 Casual   1
2018/06/07 Contract 2
2018/06/08 Casual   1
2018/06/08 Contract 1
2018/06/08 Fulltime 1
2018/06/09 Casual   1
2018/06/09 Contract 1
```

What I have tried:

```
select Date, Jobtype,'Meal'=(COUNT(Date)) 
from CanLog 
where WW BETWEEN '2018/06/06' and '2018/06/09' 
group by Date, Jobtype 
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
SELECT Date,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog as c WHERE c.WW = clog.WW AND jobtype = 'fulltime') AS Fulltime,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog as c WHERE c.WW = clog.WW AND jobtype = 'contract') AS Contract,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog as c WHERE c.WW = clog.WW AND jobtype = 'casual') AS Casual
FROM CanLog AS clog
WHERE WW BETWEEN '2018/06/06' AND '2018/06/09' 
GROUP BY Date, Jobtype 
ORDER BY Date
```

Select in parenthesis count how much of given string is in the day.
And if you write from small all enlarged letters, it doesnt matter, sql is case insensitive

Comment: It worked ,Thank you.I had to add distinct to the select Date

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your WW column comes from. I assumed it's the date column. If it's not, please adjust.

You need to use `UNPIVOT` operator and discard records that equal to 0:

```
select u.date, u.jobtype, u.meal
from canlog
unpivot
(
  meal
  for jobtype in ( fulltime, contract, casual )
) u
where 
  [Date] between '2018/06/06' and '2018/06/09'
  and meal <> 0;
```

See [**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d4495/1).

Result:

```
date        jobtype     meal
2018-06-04  Fulltime    1
2018-06-05  Fulltime    1
2018-06-06  Contract    1
2018-06-06  Casual      1
2018-06-07  Fulltime    2
2018-06-07  Contract    1
2018-06-08  Fulltime    1
2018-06-08  Contract    1
2018-06-08  Casual      1
2018-06-09  Contract    1
2018-06-09  Casual      1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  distinct Date,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog as c WHERE c.WW = clog.WW AND jobtype = 'fulltime') AS Fulltime,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog as c WHERE c.WW = clog.WW AND jobtype = 'contract') AS Contract,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CanLog as c WHERE c.WW = clog.WW AND jobtype = 'casual') AS Casual
FROM CanLog AS clog
WHERE WW BETWEEN '2018/06/06' AND '2018/06/09' 
GROUP BY Date, Jobtype 
ORDER BY Date